# Submit POST data in loop without cURL and get response data - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, api, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, sms-gateway

I have a code that sends SMS to customers that is set up as cron job. My problem is, when I use cURL, it's sending 2-part messages and our wallet is being charged twice. We have an average of 500 messages to send per day. My goal is to make the message 1-part only.

So I'm trying to find the best way to send messages in loop without using cURL.
I have thought of saving the post data from the loop in an array and send it to my view. Then when the view is called, I will automatically send the form withouth hitting the submit button and using javascript to auto submit. After the view is called, I will use file_get_contents() to get the response from the URL. But I cant make it work:

1. The view is not working inside the loop. It just works outside the loop.
2. If I pass the loop inside the view and not in the controller, how can I get the response data each loop?

My current code in CURL:

```
public function send_sms_globe(){
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    set_time_limit(0);

    //get all data from the database pull with status = queue
    $globe_data = $this->New_Sms_Api_model->get_queued_data('globe_api');

    $passphrase = '[our_pass_phrase]';
    $app_id = '[our_app_id]';
    $app_secret = '[our_app_secret]';

    $url = 'https://devapi.globelabs.com.ph/smsmessaging/v1/outbound/<our_shortcode>/requests/';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    $limit = 0;

    foreach($globe_data AS $records_data){
        if($limit == 49){
            break;
        }
        switch($limit) {
            case 49: 
                $limit = 0;
                break;

            default:
                if($records_data['Remarks'] == 'LOADED'){
                    if($records_data['sent_to'] == 'sender'){
                        $address = $records_data['sender_phone_number'];
                    }else if($records_data['sent_to'] == 'consignee'){
                        $address = $records_data['consignee_phone_number'];
                    }
                } else {
                    $address = $records_data['sender_phone_number'];
                }
                //$address = '+63917*******';//address : *subscriber number $records_data['phone_number'];
                $message = (isset($records_data['Message']) && $records_data['Message'] != '') ? $records_data['Message']:''; //message : *sms content
                $str = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', $message);
                $post_data = [
                    'app_id' => $app_id,
                    'app_secret' => $app_secret,
                    'passphrase' => $passphrase,
                    'message' => rawurlencode($str),
                    'address' => $address
                ];

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

                // execute!
                $response = curl_exec($ch);

                $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

                $queue_id = $records_data['ID'];
                $invoice_number = $records_data['InvoicecNumber'];
                $status_remark = $records_data['Remarks'];
                $record_id = $records_data['record_id'];
                if($http_code == 201 || $http_code == 200){
                    $no_of_tries = $records_data['no_of_tries'];
                    if($no_of_tries == 0){
                        $no_of_tries = 1;
                    } else {
                        $no_of_tries = $records_data['no_of_tries'];
                    }
                    $status = 'sent';
                    $retry = 0;
                } else {
                    $no_of_tries = $records_data['no_of_tries'] + 1;
                    if($no_of_tries == 3){
                        $status = 'failed';
                        $retry = 0;
                    } else {
                        $status = 'retry';
                        $retry = 1;
                    }
                }
                $update_queued_data = $this->New_Sms_Api_model->update_queued_data($queue_id, $invoice_number, $status, $retry, $no_of_tries);
                if($update_queued_data){
                    if($status == 'sent'){
                        if($status_remark == 'LOADED'){
                            $sent_to = $records_data['sent_to'];
                        } else {
                            $sent_to = NULL;
                        }
                        $this->New_Sms_Api_model->save_to_cq_sms($invoice_number, $status_remark, $record_id,$sent_to);
                        echo $records_data['record_id'].' ---- '.$status;
                    }
                    $limit++;
                }
        }    
    }
    // close the connection, release resources used
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

We have a message with 157 characters (160 max). I already talked to the API support we're using. First they suggested to format my message as URL encoding, and so I did. So from 3-part message it became 2-part. And then they said it will send as 2-part even if it's formatted that way because we use cURL. They suggested that we use PostMan but it's not for free so it's not an option.

Any ideas that can replace my current code? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your two questions (1. and 2.). "The view is not working inside the loop"? What about cURL specifically makes the thing span two SMS messages? The number of characters still no? Anyway, question is unclear.

Comment: API support sounds pretty dumb. I'd ask to speak with someone else.

Comment: When I look at the API documentation, I guess I don't see how you could possibly be sending the request correctly.  See: http://www.globelabs.com.ph/docs/#sms-sending-sms-sms-mt

Comment: @BrianGottier we were given a different URL to use because we did not use the opt in option in the doc.

Comment: @ficuscr because I thought of running the code inside a POST form and the form will be in the view. I run a loop to get each data so the view is inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the confusion. I was able to fix the issue without changing all of my code. I just removed `rawurlencode` in my string message and it's sending a 1-part message now.

Maybe using `$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', $message);` already did the trick and using `rawurlencode` after just added additional characters `ex: %20`.

Thanks everyone!